# Slow output in RStudio

Tags: r

Ouput of 1000 numbers by the command

`c(1:1000)`

takes **6 seconds** in a R Markdown. One can observe how the numbers are gradually displayed row by row. Similar oberservations with `rep(1,1000)` or `rep('1',1000)`.

This happens on a new laptop with freshly installed RStudio.
There are no other programs that work in the background and all other programs on the laptop perform quickly as expected.

Is this a built-in delay to get an impression of the amount of displayed data and how this can be switched off?

---

technical details:

OS: Win10.19042

RStudio 1.3.1093

CPU: i7-9750H (6 cores)

RAM: 32GB

---

RStudio being busy. After 3 seconds about 500 numbers were displayed. After further 3 seconds the whole output would be completed.
[image]

Comment: This is expected. It's the printing that takes time, not the actual calculation.

Comment: It completes within a second on my system.